# Graphviz using dot subgraph alignment issues

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to align two graphs in graphviz.  I'm using `dot` and below is the code I'm using.

```
digraph {
//rank=same;
q1 [shape="doublecircle"];
q2 [shape="doublecircle"];
q0->q1 
q0->q1 
q0->q1 
q1->q2 

rankdir=LR
node [shape=plaintext]
subgraph cluster_01 {
//rank=sink
label = "key";
key [label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
  <tr><td align="left" port="i1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left" port="i2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left" port="i3"></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left" port="i4"></td></tr>
  </table>>]
}
```

I would like the table that is the `key` to be under the nodes.  And I would like my nodes to line up horizontally.  I've been messing with `rank=same` to get the nodes to go horizontally and `rank=sink` to get the `key` to be under the nodes.  Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck on this for too long.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To have the node `key` under the nodes:

The order of appearance of the nodes in the script matters. In this case, if you simply define your `key` before the other nodes (`q0`, `q1`, ...), it will appear under those nodes.

The other nodes already align horizontally (they are on the same horizontal line).